# cannot import name 'EMD' from 'PyEMD' (Empirical Mode Decomposition )

Tags: python

Following import:

```py
from PyEMD import EMD, EEMD
```

results in error:

> cannot import name 'EMD' from 'PyEMD'

[image]

How to resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, please keep in mind that you are [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to try to research problems before asking. "I try to follow many ways but it does not work" does not help us; you need to show the ways that you tried, and show what happened when you tried them. Finally, do not use irrelevant tags on your question.

Comment: All of that said: did you try reading the [documentation](https://pyemd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)? In particular, did you try the sanity check described at the bottom of the front page there?

Comment: Thank for your comment. Yes, I read the document, I follow both methods and no errors happen. i only can import PyEMD, but still cannot import EMD from PyEMD.

Comment: What do you see in `dir(pyEMD)`? What version number was reported when you tried using the sanity check?

Comment: How I can apply dir(pyEMD), I only follow the second way as here : $ git clone https://github.com/laszukdawid/PyEMD and after that $ python setup.py install

Comment: When I type dir(pyEMD); some information display                                                                     (base) C:\Users\Admin>dir(pyEMD)
 Volume in drive C is Windows 10
 Volume Serial Number is 3657-E676
 Directory of C:\Users\Admin
File Not Found.                                                                                                    Thank you for your patience to help me. I am beginner

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved this problem, try renaming the folder of pyemd.

For example X:\xxx\Lib\site-packages\pyemd → X:\xxx\Lib\site-packages\PyEMD.

Besides, before renaming, we had better to install emd-signal(pip install EMD-signal). Otherwise, we can not import CEEMDAN, EEMD, and other methods based on emd.

Answer (score 0):

I use miniconda but when I install this package I use:

```
pip install EMD-signal
```

and I follow this: https://pypi.org/project/EMD-signal/

Then it works <3 Hope it helps.

Comment: The answer looks good but could benefit from some formatting improvements. You can use backticks to format commands or code snippets as code. This greatly improves the readability.

Answer (score 0):

Under a Conda environment:

firstly, i use the following command to install this Tool package

```
pip install EMD-signal
```

but it still doesnot work
and then i check my Python interpreter address. i mean i should install this tool package in python interpreter I am using in current project. so i decide install it again when i open the virtual environment(where python interpreter used in current project), and than it's useful.